# Changing CSS of menu on page scroll using height of element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Hello on my page i have three sections, the header section which contains the menu and the slider area and has a red background with white text and the content area with has a white background with black text and the footer area which has a gray background.  My menu is static meaning it shows no matter which part of the page you scroll to.

My issue however arose when i scrolled to the white part of the page, since the menu text is white on the white part of the page the text does not show.

So i decided to try and change the css on page scroll, i looked around and found this **directive** that returns the **scroll position** and using the scroll position i can **change the CSS** with **ng-class**.

```
   /**
     * Scroll Position Directive
     */
    .directive('scrollPosition', function($window) {
        return {
            scope: {
                scroll: '=scrollPosition'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var windowEl = angular.element($window);
                var handler = function() {
                    scope.scroll = windowEl.scrollTop();
                }
                windowEl.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
                handler();
            }
        };
    })
```

The above code works however i was faced with another issue, on my homepage the height of the header differs from the other pages also since my website is responsive the header size may change depending on the screen size.  Because of this i could not use a fixed height to change the class as shown in the code below:

```
ng-class="{ 'topbar': scroll > 200 }"
```

What i actually want is this:

```
 ng-class="{ 'topbar': scroll > heightOfHeader }"
```

where **heightOfHeader** is the height of my header area that can change depending on the screen size.

I have looked online for many solutions on how to get the height of my header when the page loads or when the screen size changes but i have found no solution yet, anything i try returns 0 as the height of my header.

```
.directive('elementHeight', function() {
            return {
                scope: {
                    elementHeight: '='
                },
                link: function(scope, element) {
                    /*var windowEl = angular.element($window);
                    var handler = function() {
                        scope.elementHeight = element[0].offsetHeight;
                    }
                    windowEl.on('load', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
                    handler();*/

                    /*$timeout(function(){
                        scope.elementHeight = $('#header').height();
                    });*/

                    $(window).load(function() {
                        scope.elementHeight = element[0].offsetHeight;
                    });
                }
            };
```

The commented code is older solutions i tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i finally found a solution by putting together several answers I found on stackoverflow.  For the scroll position i maintained the code i already had:

```
/**
     * Scroll Position Directive
     */
    .directive('scrollPosition', function($window) {
        return {
            scope: {
                scroll: '=scrollPosition'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var windowEl = angular.element($window);
                var handler = function() {
                    scope.scroll = windowEl.scrollTop();
                }
                windowEl.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
                handler();
            }
        };
    })
```

For the height i found this code here which i modified a bit (although i do not fully understand what is happening here myself):

```
/*
 * Get notified when height changes and change margin-top
 */
.directive( 'elHeightTarget', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ) {

            scope.$watch( '__height', function( newHeight, oldHeight ) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('elHeight', newHeight);
            } );
        }
    }
})

/*
 * Checks every $digest for height changes
 */
.directive( 'elHeightSource', function() {

    return {
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ) {

            scope.$watch( function() {
                scope.__height = elem.height();
            } );
        }
    }

})
```

In the elHeightTarget directive i added a **$rootScope.$broadcast** inside the **scope.$watch** to broadcast any **changes in height** of the target element.

Then inside my Main Controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', function($http, $scope, $state, $rootScope) {

    $scope.height = 0;
    $scope.scroll = 0;

    $scope.$on('elHeight', function(events, args){
        $scope.height = args;
    });

}])
```

Finally in my HTML i watch use ng-class to change the class of my menu based on the scroll position and height of my header:

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="menu" scroll-position="scroll" ng-class="{ 'menu-default': scroll < height, 'menu-red': scroll > height  }">
        <div class="container">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This the html of my header where I add the directive that checks for any changes in height:

```
<div id="header" class="header" el-height-target el-height-source>
    ...
</div>
```

That's all :) i dunno if there is a much easier and better way of doing this but this definitely solved my problem. :)